# GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()

Tags: development

is there a way to pass a parameter to the GetSubwebsForCurrentUser() function?
I'm needing to get the subwebs for specific users - not the current user. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can impersonate a particular user, but obviously this involves re-creation of SPSite and SPWeb objects. Thus please use this approach carefully: calling the code from a loop can cause unwanted performance leak.

```
//get this current user's user token
SPUserToken userToken = web.AllUsers[user].UserToken;

//create an SPSite object in the context of this user
using (SPSite s = new SPSite(siteStr, userToken))
{

    using (SPWeb w = s.OpenWeb())
    {
       // use w.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser() here
    }
}
```

More details and explanations here: http://blackninjasoftware.com/2009/04/09/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Dangit... you guys beat me. Also, [Keith Dahlby has a pretty interesting post](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/) about doing this for the system account.

Comment: Thanks, looks like we'll need to write a good method for this...

Answer (score 1):

You can impersonate other users when opening an SPSite (and thus a web below it)

```
SPUserToken userToken = web.AllUsers[user].UserToken;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl, userToken))
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
   {
    // ...
   }
}
```

But I would not guarantee the performance if you are looping through many users..